# Basic concepts in quantum theory to start learning semiconductor physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, education, semiconductor-physics

What basic concepts in quantum theory one must known to start learning semiconductor physics?

Comment: You would want to know basics such as particle in a infinite well and finite well. Understand the wave nature of quantum mechanics. Next thing you would want to know is Blochs theorem and the idea of band theory coming from electron in a periodic potential. Understand how the dispersion relation is related to crystal momentum and how to get electron momentum from the dispersion... Semiconductor physics is very involved and takes much time to understand. It would take more than a SE post to answer.

Comment: Can you suggest some books or links from which i can understand these things?

Comment: I would suggest David J. Griffiths Quantum Mechanics. It is a solid book. R. Shankar's QM book is pretty good as well. For Solid State/Semiconductor books I have not found one that I really liked. Ashcroft and Mermin is good one, but very advanced. You could always read reviews of books on Amazon.